# save data into Hadoop using sparkR - crash

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

First thing I'd try is to load a 2G txt file into R and save it into Hadoop.

My laptop has 4 cores and 16G RAM. The RAM usage is:

```
2G RAM - windows and other apps
8G RAM - after loading data using read.csv
16G RAM - crashed when trying to save data into Hadoop using `df = createDataFrame(sqlContext, dat)`
```

Anybody know how to avoid crashing the RAM in this case? Or is sparkR not a good tool to load data and save into Hadoop? (I can use other Hadoop tools and python too) Thanks

Code:

```
library(rJava)

if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
    Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = 'D:\\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6')
}

library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

sc = sparkR.init(master = "local[*]", 
                 sparkEnvir = list(spark.driver.memory = '4g'))

sqlContext = sparkRSQL.init(sc)

setwd('D:\\data\\Medicare_Provider_Util_Payment_PUF_CY2013')

dat = read.csv('Medicare_Provider_Util_Payment_PUF_CY2013.txt', header = T, sep = '\t', row.names = NULL)
head(dat)


df = createDataFrame(sqlContext, dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dat = read.csv('Medicare_Provider_Util_Payment_PUF_CY2013.txt', header = T, sep = '\t', row.names = NULL)


#Option 1:
#You can save it as hive tables
hiveContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
createDataFrame(hiveContext, dat) %>% saveAsTable("Hive_DataBase.HiveTable")

#Option 2:
#You can save as Parquet format
df = createDataFrame(sqlContext, dat)
write.df(df, path="df_1.parquet", source="parquet", mode="overwrite")
```